# node-postgres returning undefined result

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

When i try to get result from node-postgres from my express app, pool.query is returning undefined result when i log it in console. Not sure if its about database connected properly or I am not returning the result properly? I am using heroku to deploy the app and using connection string given by heroku. Cant figure it out, anyone there to help please?.

db.js:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const conString = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: conString,
        ssl: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
});
module.exports ={
    getResult: (sql, params, callback)=>{
        pool.query(sql, [params], (error, results)=>{
            console.log(results);
            if(!error){
                callback(results);
            }else{
                callback(null);
            }
            pool.end();
        });
    }
}
```

user-model.js

```
var db = require('./db');

module.exports ={
    findUserById: (userId)=>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            var sql = "select id from users where id=?";
            db.getResult(sql, [userId], (result)=>{
                if(result.length>0){
                    resolve(true);
                }else{
                    resolve(false);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems the sent query parameter is in mysql format, use node-postgres format which is `var sql = "select id from users where id = $1";` which should return valid result

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your use of `params` is not correct.

You're passing an array to `db.getResult()`, then using it as the first element of another array.

Should just be `pool.query(sql, params, (error, results)=>{` on that line.

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the pool connection

```js
const pool = require('./pool');

module.exports = {
  // my version
  findUserById(sql, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return pool
        .connect()
        .then(conn => {
          conn
            .query(sql, [params])
            .then(result => {
              conn.release()
              resolve(result)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              conn.release()
              reject(error)
            })
        })
    })
  },
  
  // your version
  findUserByIds: (userId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var sql = "select id from users where id=?";
      db.getResult(sql, [userId], (result) => {
        if (result.length > 0) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

//// in you main or you controller file
   // use the function
const { findUserById } = require('./model')

app.get('/user/:id', (req, res) => {
  let sql = 'select * from "users" where "userId"= $1';
  findUserById(sql, 1)
  .then(result => {
    res.status(200).send({
      data: result
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.status(400).send(error)
  })
})
```